# Is there a way to make this code more efficient?

Tags: java

```
public int Neighbours(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate)
{
    xCoordinate -= 1;
    yCoordinate -= 1;
    int NeighbourCounter = 0;
    int incrementer = 0;
    int m1 = -1; //istart
    int n1 = -1; //jstart
    int m2 = 1; //iend
    int n2 = 1; //jend

    if (xCoordinate == 0)
    {
        m1 = 1;
    }

    if (yCoordinate == 0)
    {
        n1 = -1;
    }

    if (xCoordinate + 1 == yLen)
    {
        m2 = 0;
    }

    if (yCoordinate + 1 == xLen)
    {
        n2 = 0;
    }

    for (int xNeighbour = m1; xNeighbour <= m2; xNeighbour++)
    {
        if (xNeighbour == 0)
        {
            incrementer = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            incrementer = 1;
        }

        for (int yNeighbour = n1; yNeighbour<n2; yNeighbour += incrementer)
        {
            if (CurrentGen[yCoordinate + yNeighbour][xCoordinate + xNeighbour] == 1)
            {
                NeighbourCounter++;
            }

        }
    }
    return NeighbourCounter;
}
```

Is it possible to make this code more efficient? This code is for my Game of Life project, and I seem to be getting an error when I try to run this code for the next generation of the game of life. For my NextGeneration I seem to be getting an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException: -2`. This error occurs in the line 45.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: First fix it, then think about make it more efficient.

Comment: please show the data you use as input, the calls, the result and the expected result. also chage int NeighbourCounter =0; to lowercase int neighbourCounter =0;

Comment: Also use lowercase for variables and functions as defined in the Java style guidelines.

Comment: Would you like to improve performance or fix the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: This is **non-working** code. This does **not** belong on code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Joiner - I need to fix the code, im not sure how to fix the OutOfBoundsException

Comment: However, after fixing it, if a code review for code efficiency is desired, then post that as a separate question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (and not on SO).

Comment: Line 44 is a `{`. Please format the code properly.

Comment: @Joiner - changed to line 45

Comment: Never write left justified code.

Comment: It is hard to help you with the current code. I am going to add a little answer, but please improve your question. You should browse the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

---

```
if(CurrentGen[yCoordinate + yNeighbour][xCoordinate + xNeighbour] == 1)
```

You are accessing `CurrentGen`.
`yCoordinate + yNeighbour` or `xCoordinate + xNeighbour` equals `-2`. Arrays start from index `0`.